# Asking Excel To pick the value from the first row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Lets say you have two rows in excel

```
     S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 S6
ROW1 1   2  3  4  5  6
ROW2 7   8  9  10 11 12
```

I wish to have excel go through the numbers in the second row and give the name from the first row as the output.

Like for example if I ask for 1, then excel should give S1.

I have been trying to use HLOOKUP("value"; array; 2; FALSE), but it doesn't seem to work. It works if I turn the rows around so that the names are second row while the numbers are first. But that is not an option since I have multiple rows and I have to apply that formula to each row.

Is there a way around to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With data like:

[image]

In **G2** enter *1* and in **H2** enter:

```
=INDEX(1:1,,MATCH(G2,A2:F2,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thank You :)

Comment: This is correct. HLookUp and VLookUp look something up then go either down or right. You can't go up or left. To go in those directions you should use Index/Match. Or the new XLookUp I guess but why use a subscription-only formula when existing formulas already work just fine?

Comment: @BartHumphries  Thank you for the comments.  I agree with you 100%.